# String.split in IE

Tags: javascript

If I try this code in firefox it works fine

```
 var words = String.split(new RegExp(/[\-\s]/));
 words // ["/[\-\s]/"]
```

The same code in IE not!

```
 var words = String.split(new RegExp(/[\-\s]/));
 words "Object doesn't support property or method 'split'"
```

Why? and what is the best way to fix it in IE?

Comment: Do you have a variable called `String` or are you trying to access the `String` object?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Don't you want to split a specific string instead? Firefox's output doesn't look very useful anyway.

Comment: I am trying to access the String object

Comment: Why did you remove the relevant code from the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**:

The problem is that your argument is called `string` (all lower case), but you're using `String` (with an initial capital) when you're trying to split it. JavaScript is a case-sensitive language, `string !== String`.

So change this:

```
var words = String.split(new RegExp(/[\-\s]/)),
```

to this:

```
var words = string.split(new RegExp(/[\-\s]/)),
//          ^--- lower case s
```

---

**Original answer**:

`split` is a function on the `String.prototype` (effectively, on instances of strings), not on `String` itself (the constructor function).

So:

```
var words = "some words and hyphenated-words here".split(/[\-\s]/);
console.log(words); // ["some", "words", "and", "hyphenated", "words", "here"]
```

---

Side note: You don't have to wrap a regular expression literal (`/[\-\s]/`) in `new RegExp(...)` unless you're working around an old <s>bug</s> *issue* in some implementations around the global flag and caching/reuse of local literals across function calls, which isn't relevant to `split` as you don't use the `g` flag with it.

Comment: thanks but my question is slightly different...please read the full code I am implementing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `String` object itself has a `split()` method. `split()` is a method of `String` instances:

```
'a b c'.split(/\s/); //returns ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

`split` method shouldn't apply to String class but to a string like:

```
"abc-123 def-456".split(/[\-\s]/);
```